# Hive - external (dynamically) partitioned table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm having a table in MySQL viz. nas_comps.

```
select comp_code, count(leg_id) from nas_comps_01012011_31012011 n group by comp_code;
comp_code     count(leg_id)
'J'           20640
'Y'           39680
```

First, I imported data onto HDFSHadoop version 1.0.2) using Sqoop :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://172.25.37.135/pros_olap2 \
--username hadoopranch \
--password hadoopranch \
--query "select * from nas_comps where dep_date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-10' AND \$CONDITIONS" \
-m 1 \
--target-dir /pros/olap2/dataimports/nas_comps
```

Then, I created an external, partitioned Hive table :

```
/*shows the partitions on 'describe' but not 'show partitions'*/
create external table  nas_comps(DS_NAME string,DEP_DATE string,
                                 CRR_CODE string,FLIGHT_NO string,ORGN string,
                                 DSTN string,PHYSICAL_CAP int,ADJUSTED_CAP int,
                                 CLOSED_CAP int)
PARTITIONED BY (LEG_ID int, month INT, COMP_CODE string)
location '/pros/olap2/dataimports/nas_comps'
```

The partition columns are shown when described :

```
hive> describe extended nas_comps;
OK
ds_name string
dep_date        string
crr_code        string
flight_no       string
orgn    string
dstn    string
physical_cap    int
adjusted_cap    int
closed_cap      int
leg_id  int
month   int
comp_code       string

Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:nas_comps, dbName:pros_olap2_optim, 
owner:hadoopranch, createTime:1374849456, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, 
sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:ds_name, type:string, comment:null), 
FieldSchema(name:dep_date, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:crr_code, 
type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:flight_no, type:string, comment:null), 
FieldSchema(name:orgn, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:dstn, type:string, 
comment:null), FieldSchema(name:physical_cap, type:int, comment:null), 
FieldSchema(name:adjusted_cap, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:closed_cap, 
type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:leg_id, type:int, comment:null), 
FieldSchema(name:month, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:comp_code, type:string, 
comment:null)], location:hdfs://172.25.37.21:54300/pros/olap2/dataimports/nas_comps, 
inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, 
outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, 
numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, 
serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:
{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}), partitionKeys:
[FieldSchema(name:leg_id, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:month, type:int,
comment:null), FieldSchema(name:comp_code, type:string, comment:null)], 
parameters:{EXTERNAL=TRUE, transient_lastDdlTime=1374849456}, viewOriginalText:null, 
viewExpandedText:null, tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)
```

**But I'm not sure if the partitions are created because :**

```
hive> show partitions nas_comps;
OK
Time taken: 0.599 seconds


select count(1) from nas_comps;
```

returns 0 records

How do I create an external Hive table with dynamic partitions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hive will not create the partitions for you this way.
Just create a table partitioned by the desired partition key, then execute `insert overwrite table` from the external table to the new partitioned table (setting `hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true` and `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict`).

If you must keep the table partitioned externally you have to manually create the directories (1 directory per partition the name should be `PARTION_KEY=VALUE`)
then use the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;` [command](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Recoverpartitions)

Answer (score 10):

**Dynamic Partition**

Partition gets added dynamically during inserting the record into hive table.

1. Support only with insert statement.
2. Not supported with `load data` statement.
3. Need to enable dynamic partition settings before inserting data into hive table.
    `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict` default value is `strict`
    `hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true` default value is `false`.

**Dynamic Partition Query**

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
INSERT INTO table_name PARTITION (loaded_date)
select * from table_name1 where loaded_date = 20151217
```

Here `loaded_date = 20151217` is partition and its value.

**Limitations:**

1. Dynamic partition will work with above statement only.
2. It will create  the partition dynamically as per the data which it select from the `loaded_date` column from the `table_name1`;

If your condition doesn't match with above criteria, then:

First create a partitioned table then do like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION (DS_NAME='partname1',DATE='partname2');
```

or Please use this  [Link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicpartitionInsert) for Dynamic Partition creation.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked this but these are not dynamic partitions - one still has to provide values for the partitions.

Comment: Right, Run it through shell script.You can create a variable in shell script for partition and pass it in alter table command, otherwise no option available currently :(